# add animation in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

how can I add animation in cocos2d in a sprite, the problem is that whenever the use fire the object and hits that object, the object will remove just like an animation .. if you have any tutorial then plz send it to me...

thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use spritesheets of images and then do animation using the images.

For code examples you can try the following tutorial.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d

Answer (score 0):

just use this

```
    CCSpriteSheet *mgr = [CCSpriteSheet spriteSheetWithFile:@"yourImage.png" capacity:5];
    [self addChild:mgr z:0 tag:4];    //set the image and load it to the CCLayer

    sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:mgr.texture rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    [sprite runAction:[CCFadeTo actionWithDuration: 1 opacity:80]];
```

Comment: but WHat about the images? I want to use animations with images

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of examples coming with cocos2d. Including animation using a set of images. Take a look at SpriteTest example - it's what you are looking for